# How to add Google-Tag-Manager trigger by a script availability in html code?

Tags: google-tag-manager

So I have website with many categories. And I want to trigger submit button for exactly chosen category. My url is not have any ID for that category. So I want to add trigger by html code availability. Every category have some sort of code with ID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yaParams = {"design" : "new_11"};
</script>
```

How can I add trigger by that piece of code? Just availability.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a push to dataLayer with an event:

```
dataLayer.push({"event" : "mytrigger", "design" : "new_11"});
```

Then you can create a **custom event trigger** with event name `mytrigger`.

Comment: thanks for an answer. So there is no way to make it without adding code on website?

Comment: You can do it from GTM too. If you don't have specific references (id, class, attr, ...) on the page you must have a good command of the DOM.